# Oracle JDeveloper 12C & Integrated Weblogic Server not running windows 10

Tags: java, weblogic, jdeveloper

I want to create Weblogic Default Domain I get the following error. Can you help with information. I'am using Oracle JDeveloper 12.2.1.1.0 Generic

thanks

> [Waiting for the domain to finish building...] [05:21:01 PM]
>   IntegratedWebLogicServer Domain is invalid.  Regenerating it...
>   [05:21:02 PM] Creating IntegratedWebLogicServer Domain... The Server
>   Instance cannot be started because the IntegratedWebLogicServer Domain
>   was not built successfully. [05:21:29 PM] ERROR:  An error occurred
>   while building the default domain. Please see this log file for more
>   details:
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.1.42.160607.2047\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain.log

BuildDefaultDomain.log file content

```
Adding environment variable to WLST script USER_MEM_ARGS = -Xms32m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
Log File:      C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.1.42.160607.2047\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain.log
Label:         JDEVADF_12.2.1.1.0_GENERIC_160607.2047.S
Product Home:  C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\
Domain:        C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.1.42.160607.2047\DefaultDomain

BuildDefaultDomain1.py      2016-09-28 17:21:02

cmd.exe /c ""C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.1.42.160607.2047\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py""
Process started
wlst > 
wlst > Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
wlst > 
wlst > Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
wlst > 
wlst > Type help() for help on available commands
wlst > 
wlst > Creating Default Domain
wlst > [progress] Reading template: Basic WebLogic Server Domain
wlst > Setting Name to 'DefaultServer'
wlst > Setting ListenAddress to '127.0.0.1'
wlst > Setting ListenPort to 7101
wlst > Enabling SSL using port 7102
wlst > Setting domain administrator to 'weblogic'
wlst > Setting domain password.
wlst > [progress] Writing domain: /C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/JDeveloper/system12.2.1.1.42.160607.2047/DefaultDomain/
wlst > [progress] Closing template.
wlst > [progress] Reading domain: /C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/JDeveloper/system12.2.1.1.42.160607.2047/DefaultDomain/
wlst > [progress] Adding domain extension template: Oracle ADRS 
wlst > [progress] Updating domain.
wlst > [progress] Closing domain.
wlst > [progress] Reading domain: /C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/JDeveloper/system12.2.1.1.42.160607.2047/DefaultDomain/
wlst > [progress] Adding domain extension template: Oracle JRF 
wlst > [progress] Updating domain.
wlst > Error: runCmd() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
wlst > com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: Error updating domain:
wlst > 64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
wlst > 64254: Encountered error: SecurityContext:
wlst >  Domain Name: DefaultDomain
wlst >  Persistence Type: FILE
wlst >  Platform: WLS
wlst >  Scratch Dir: scratch
wlst >  Reconfig Domain: false
wlst >  Shared Secret Store: null
wlst >  Extension: true
wlst >  DisableManagementOperations: false
wlst > 64254: Check log for more detail.
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.CommandExceptionHandler.handleException(CommandExceptionHandler.java:69)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.handleException(WLScriptContext.java:2666)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.runCmd(WLScriptContext.java:698)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyInstance.invoke(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.pycode._pyx5.command$1(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni1649198741705970756.py:19)
wlst >  at org.python.pycode._pyx5.call_function(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni1649198741705970756.py)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.pycode._pyx5.updateDomain$31(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni1649198741705970756.py:135)
wlst >  at org.python.pycode._pyx5.call_function(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni1649198741705970756.py)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.pycode._pyx98.f$0(C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.1.42.160607.2047\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py:125)
wlst >  at org.python.pycode._pyx98.call_function(C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.1.42.160607.2047\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.PyCode.call(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(Unknown Source)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.WLST.main(WLST.java:181)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at weblogic.WLST.main(WLST.java:47)
wlst > Caused by: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptException: Error updating domain:
wlst > 64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
wlst > 64254: Encountered error: SecurityContext:
wlst >  Domain Name: DefaultDomain
wlst >  Persistence Type: FILE
wlst >  Platform: WLS
wlst >  Scratch Dir: scratch
wlst >  Reconfig Domain: false
wlst >  Shared Secret Store: null
wlst >  Extension: true
wlst >  DisableManagementOperations: false
wlst > 64254: Check log for more detail.
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTState.processCommand(WLSTState.java:241)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.runCmd(WLScriptContext.java:692)
wlst >  ... 30 more
wlst > Caused by: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: Error updating domain:
wlst > 64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
wlst > 64254: Encountered error: SecurityContext:
wlst >  Domain Name: DefaultDomain
wlst >  Persistence Type: FILE
wlst >  Platform: WLS
wlst >  Scratch Dir: scratch
wlst >  Reconfig Domain: false
wlst >  Shared Secret Store: null
wlst >  Extension: true
wlst >  DisableManagementOperations: false
wlst > 64254: Check log for more detail.
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.updateDomain(WLScriptContext.java:1112)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTState.processCommand(WLSTState.java:224)
wlst >  ... 31 more
wlst > Caused by: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptException: 64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
wlst > 64254: Encountered error: SecurityContext:
wlst >  Domain Name: DefaultDomain
wlst >  Persistence Type: FILE
wlst >  Platform: WLS
wlst >  Scratch Dir: scratch
wlst >  Reconfig Domain: false
wlst >  Shared Secret Store: null
wlst >  Extension: true
wlst >  DisableManagementOperations: false
wlst > 64254: Check log for more detail.
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptExecutor.runProgressOperator(ScriptExecutor.java:5460)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.ScriptExecutor.updateDomain(ScriptExecutor.java:2505)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.updateDomain(WLScriptContext.java:1107)
wlst >  ... 36 more
wlst > Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
wlst >   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.1.42.160607.2047\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py", line 125, in ?
wlst >   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni1649198741705970756.py", line 135, in updateDomain
wlst >   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\WLSTOfflineIni1649198741705970756.py", line 19, in command
wlst > 64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
wlst > 64254: Encountered error: SecurityContext:
wlst >  Domain Name: DefaultDomain
wlst >  Persistence Type: FILE
wlst >  Platform: WLS
wlst >  Scratch Dir: scratch
wlst >  Reconfig Domain: false
wlst >  Shared Secret Store: null
wlst >  Extension: true
wlst >  DisableManagementOperations: false
wlst > 64254: Check log for more detail.
wlst > 
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.CommandExceptionHandler.handleException(CommandExceptionHandler.java:69)
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.handleException(WLScriptContext.java:2666)
wlst > 
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.runCmd(WLScriptContext.java:698)
wlst > 
wlst >  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
wlst > 
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst > 
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst > 
wlst > 
wlst > com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: Error updating domain:
wlst > 64254: Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution
wlst > 64254: Encountered error: SecurityContext:
wlst >  Domain Name: DefaultDomain
wlst >  Persistence Type: FILE
wlst >  Platform: WLS
wlst >  Scratch Dir: scratch
wlst >  Reconfig Domain: false
wlst >  Shared Secret Store: null
wlst >  Extension: true
wlst >  DisableManagementOperations: false
wlst > 64254: Check log for more detail.
wlst > 
wlst > 
wlst > Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
Elapsed time:  27090 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue recently.
The detailed logs will be available in `/tmp/wlstOfflineLogs_*` directory.
The detailed log had the actual issue. In my case, it happened to be file permissions.

> "Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /scratch/u01/product/fmw/wls_odi/oracle_common/modules/oracle.jps/domain_config/wls/system-jazn-data.xml
>   (Permission denied)"

The directory `/u01/product/fmw/wls_odi` was the weblogic home.
After fixing the permissions issue, the installation went through fine.